# Is this possible in SQL? Min and Max Dates On a Total. Where it changes in between Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to write a query that will give me the correct historical data between dates. But only using sql. I know it is possible coding a loop, but I'm not sure if this is possible in a SQL query. Dates: DD/MM/YYYY

An Example of Data

| ID | Points | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 01/01/2018 |
| 1 | 20 | 02/01/2019 |
| 1 | 25 | 03/01/2020 |
| 1 | 10 | 04/01/2021 |

With a simple query

```
SELECT ID, Points, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID,POINTS
```

The Min date for 10 points would be 01/01/2018, and the Max Date would be 04/01/2021. Which would be wrong in this instance. As It should be:

| ID | Points | Min DATE | Max DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 01/01/2018 | 01/01/2019 |
| 1 | 20 | 02/01/2019 | 02/01/2020 |
| 1 | 25 | 03/01/2020 | 03/01/2021 |
| 1 | 10 | 04/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |

I was thinking of using LAG, but need some ideas here. What I haven't told you is there is a record per day. So I would need to group until a change of points. This is to create a view from the data that I already have.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to use `lead()`, presumably on the data once it's been aggregated  - which you haven't shown.

Comment: What denotes the order of the ID's the "Date"?  max Date would be then... pseudo `lead(Date) - 1 month? over (partition by ID order by Date asc)` and to handle the last entry coalease the value to be equal to the min date if no lead value found)

Comment: Please include the expected result in the question. It's not 100% clear [to me].

Comment: Your sample data does not include cases for your "need to group until a change of points" requirement. I suggest adding some rows with repeated ID and point values, but with different dates preceding the next change. As for the last case, setting Max DATE equal to Min DATE is a but unusual. If there is no following entry, I would presume that the effective data range would have no upper bound. In this case a NULL value (or a fixed "end of time" far future date) may be more appropriate. Logic that later asks "what Points value applies to 05 Jan 2021" may more easily select the correct record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the MAX date to be 1 day before the next MIN date.

And you can use the window function `LEAD` to get the next MIN date.
And if you group also by the year, then the date ranges match the expected result.

> ```
> SELECT ID, Points
> , MIN([Date]) AS [Min Date] 
> , COALESCE(DATEADD(day, -1, LEAD(MIN([Date])) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MIN([Date]))), MAX([Date])) AS [Max Date] 
> FROM your_table
> GROUP BY ID, Points, YEAR([Date]);
> ```

> | ID | Points | Min Date | Max Date |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 10 | 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
> | 1 | 20 | 2019-01-02 | 2020-01-02 |
> | 1 | 25 | 2020-01-03 | 2021-01-03 |
> | 1 | 10 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-04 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5a0a9897a3535226f9612d0a1cb35c5)*

Comment: @TN Well, since the dates are in different years, it could be simplified anyway.

Comment: I don't think your changes are yielding correct results for the general case. In particular, the group by year is not consistent with the OP statement that "there is a record per day". Differences in year should not matter in the progression of dates. Your original answer seemed closer, but I found some cases where duplicate Rnk values were calculated for what should be distinct groups. (Prior comment was withdrawn).

Comment: @TN You are right about how that double row_number trick can generate duplicate ranks. It's why I like the summing flags trick more (what you used in 1 of the solutions). But it's normally not a problem, as long it can separate the gaps and islands. F.e. in this case, you'd group also on points and rank, but the dup rank would have other points, so they become separated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like - for your sample data set - the following `lead` should suffice:

```
select id, points, date as MinDate, 
  IsNull(DateAdd(day, -1, Lead(Date,1) over(partition by Id order by Date)), Date) as MaxDate
from t
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0002cb734e80016e0af26510a474256)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by creating two tables one with the minimum and one with the maximum date for each grouping and then combining them

```
CREATE TABLE dataa(
    id INT,
    points INT,
    ddate DATE);
INSERT INTO dataa values(1 , 10 ,'2018-10-01');
INSERT INTO dataa values(1 , 20 ,'2019-01-02');
INSERT INTO dataa values(1 , 25 ,'2020-01-03');
INSERT INTO dataa values(1 , 10 ,'2021-01-04');
SELECT 
    mi.id, mi.points,mi.date minDate, ma.date maxDate 
FROM
    (select id, points, min(ddate) date from dataa group by id,points) mi 
JOIN
    (select id, points, max(ddate) date from dataa group by id,points) ma 
ON
    mi.id = ma.id
AND
    mi.points = ma.points;
DROP TABLE dataa;
```

this gives the following output

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+
| id   | points | minDate    | maxDate    |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
|    1 |     10 | 2018-10-01 | 2021-01-04 |
|    1 |     20 | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 |
|    1 |     25 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-03 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
```

I've used the default date formatting. This could be modified if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

*** *See my other answer, as I don't think this answer is correct after reexamining the OPs question. Leaving ths answer in place, in case it has any value.*

As I understand the problem consecutive daily values with the same value for a given ID may be ignored. This can be done by examining the prior value using the `LAG()` function and excluding records where the current value is unchanged from the prior.

From the remaining records, the `LEAD()` function can be used to look ahead to the next included record to extract the date where this value is superseded. Max Date is then calculated as one day prior.

Below is an example that includes expanded test data to cover multiple IDs and repeated Points values.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Id INT, Points INT, Date DATE)
INSERT @Data
VALUES
    (1, 10, '2018-01-01'), -- Start
    (1, 20, '2019-01-02'), -- Updated
    (1, 25, '2020-01-03'), -- Updated
    (1, 10, '2021-01-04'), -- Updated
    (2, 10, '2022-01-01'), -- Start
    (2, 20, '2022-02-01'), -- Updated
    (2, 20, '2022-03-01'), -- No change
    (2, 20, '2022-04-01'), -- No change
    (2, 20, '2022-05-01'), -- No change
    (2, 25, '2022-06-01'), -- Updated
    (2, 25, '2022-07-01'), -- No change
    (2, 20, '2022-08-01'), -- Updated
    (2, 25, '2022-09-08'), -- Updated
    (2, 10, '2022-10-09'), -- Updated
    (3, 10, '2022-01-01'), -- Start
    (3, 10, '2022-01-02'), -- No change
    (3, 20, '2022-01-03'), -- Updated
    (3, 20, '2022-01-04'), -- No change
    (3, 20, '2022-01-05'), -- No change
    (3, 10, '2022-01-06'), -- Updated
    (3, 10, '2022-01-07'); -- No change

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, PriorPoints = LAG(Points) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date)
    FROM @Data
)
SELECT ID, Points, MinDate = Date,
    MaxDate = DATEADD(day, -1, (LEAD(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date)))
FROM CTE
WHERE (PriorPoints <> Points OR PriorPoints IS NULL) -- Exclude unchanged
ORDER BY Id, Date
```

Results:

| ID | Points | MinDate | MaxDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
| 1 | 20 | 2019-01-02 | 2020-01-02 |
| 1 | 25 | 2020-01-03 | 2021-01-03 |
| 1 | 10 | 2021-01-04 | null |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2 | 20 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-05-31 |
| 2 | 25 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-07-31 |
| 2 | 20 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-09-07 |
| 2 | 25 | 2022-09-08 | 2022-10-08 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-10-09 | null |
| 3 | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | 20 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-05 |
| 3 | 10 | 2022-01-06 | null |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3950d3ab01a64c0203be6c7a8cce292)

For the last value for a given ID, the calculated MaxDate is NULL indicating no upper bound to the date range. If you really want MaxDate = MinDate for this case, you can add `ISNULL( ..., Date)`.

Comment: Hi,

This is an excellent solution to the problem, and you are correct this needs to be put into a table and then view pulled of of that. You solution will also help change that process to create the historic data. However this will require a db restructure, so my suggestion was a quick fix view, then rebuild the db to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

(I am adding this as an alternative (and simpler) interpretation of the OP's question.)

Problem restatement: Given a collection if IDs, Dates, and Points values, a group is defined as any consecutive sequence of the same Points value for a given ID and ascending dates. For each such group, calculate the min and max dates.

The start of such a group can be identified as a row where the Points value changes from the preceding value, or if there is no preceding value for a given ID.  If we first tag such rows (NewGroup = 1), we can then assign group numbers based on a count of preceding tagged rows (including the current row). Once we have assigned group numbers, it is then a simple matter to apply a group and aggregate operation.

Below is a sample that includes some additional test data to show multiple IDs and repeating values.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Id INT, Points INT, Date DATE)
INSERT @Data
VALUES
    (1, 10, '2018-01-01'), -- Start
    (1, 20, '2019-01-02'), -- Updated
    (1, 25, '2020-01-03'), -- Updated
    (1, 10, '2021-01-04'), -- Updated
    (2, 10, '2022-01-01'), -- Start
    (2, 20, '2022-02-01'), -- Updated
    (2, 20, '2022-03-01'), -- No change
    (2, 20, '2022-04-01'), -- No change
    (2, 20, '2022-05-01'), -- No change
    (2, 25, '2022-06-01'), -- Updated
    (2, 25, '2022-07-01'), -- No change
    (2, 20, '2022-08-01'), -- Updated
    (2, 25, '2022-09-08'), -- Updated
    (2, 10, '2022-10-09'), -- Updated
    (3, 10, '2022-01-01'), -- Start
    (3, 10, '2022-01-02'), -- No change
    (3, 20, '2022-01-03'), -- Updated
    (3, 20, '2022-01-04'), -- No change
    (3, 20, '2022-01-05'), -- No change
    (3, 10, '2022-01-06'), -- Updated
    (3, 10, '2022-01-07'); -- No change
```

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
        PriorPoints = LAG(Points) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date)
    FROM @Data
)
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        NewGroup = CASE WHEN (PriorPoints <> Points OR PriorPoints IS NULL)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM CTE
)
, CTE3 AS (
    SELECT *, GroupNo = SUM(NewGroup) OVER(
        PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY Date
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        )
    FROM CTE2
)
SELECT Id, Points, MinDate = MIN(Date), MaxDate = MAX(Date)
FROM CTE3
GROUP BY Id, GroupNo, Points
ORDER BY Id, GroupNo
```

Results:

| Id | Points | MinDate | MaxDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
| 1 | 20 | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 |
| 1 | 25 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-03 |
| 1 | 10 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-04 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 20 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 25 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-07-01 |
| 2 | 20 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 2 | 25 | 2022-09-08 | 2022-09-08 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-10-09 | 2022-10-09 |
| 3 | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | 20 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-05 |
| 3 | 10 | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-07 |

To see the intermediate results, replace the final select with `SELECT * FROM CTE3 ORDER BY Id, Date`.

If you wish to treat gaps in dates as group criteria, add a PriorDate calculation to CTE and add `OR Date <> PriorDate` to the NewGroup condition.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e9d66be55c4c781d529e20bd58ee2fc)

**Caution:** In your original post, you state that "this is to create a view". Beware that if the above logic is included in a view, the entire result may be recalculated every time the view is accessed, regardless of any ID or date criteria applied. It might make more sense to use the above to populate and periodically refresh a historic roll-up data table for efficient access. Another alternative is to make a stored procedure with appropriate parameters that could filter that data before feeding it into the above.